# finding inflection points in restricted cubic splines

Tags: r, spline, rms

I'd like to investigate the nonlinear relationship between independent and dependent variables. I've done this with the RMS package.

```
library(rms)
test_model <- ols(BMD_ALL ~ rcs(BMI, 4)+gender+age,data=test,x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjpaf.png)
I want to further find the inflection point, but I failed as *f(lower) * f(upper) > 0*

```
f <- Function(test_model)
uniroot_out <- uniroot(f = f,    # Find root
                       interval = c(20, 35))
uniroot_out
```

What should I do?

Comment: The inflection point is where the 2nd derivative changes sign.  You're testing where the function changes sign.  I don't know how `Function()` was defined, but you need to define it to return the 2nd derivative of the fitted model.

Comment: BTW, it's not obvious from the image that your sample function has any inflection points.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for your reply. I can't seem to get the exact expression.

Comment: @user2554330 I want to find the point where its rise changes from fast to slow